# Children component height received as a prop from Parent component is not set

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-table

I want to make a child component height equal to parent component. To get parent height I use useRef and useEffect hooks, like below:

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
const ref = useRef();
 
useEffect(() => {
        setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
    });
```

When I console.log(height) it shows me actual height of the parent and typeof height is number.

This is how it's rendered:

```
 <StyledTableHeader
                                            key={idx}
                                            isSorted={column.isSorted}
                                            key={column.id}
                                            {...column.getHeaderProps({})}
                                            style={{
                                                whiteSpace:
                                                    !matches && 'unset',
                                            }}
                                            ref={ref}
                                        >
                                            {matches ? (
                                                <RenderDesktopVersion
                                                    column={column}
                                                    idx={idx}
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <RenderMobileVersion
                                                    column={column}
                                                    idx={idx}
                                                    height={height}
                                                />
                                            )}
                                        </StyledTableHeader>
```

And this is how it looks in Styled Components:

```
export const StyledHeaderWrapperMobile = styled.div`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: ${(props: any) => props.height};
```

`;

I want to use this code only for mobile version, where header of one column is driving height of all headers, and then all children components updates their header accordingly.

In the picture below You can see that header "status" don't fill full parent, console.log shows height of 93, and 93 is the height of the header one to the right ( the highest one )
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks for helping and showing where I do wrong

Comment: What are you trying to do that normal css can't handle? There are many options like `height: 100%` or `flex: 1` etc that will fill to bounding height

Comment: the problem is the it's not working with flexbox, that's why I try to assign height as variable. All the time children don't get parent height

Comment: I'm fairly certain css will work here. Can you add a code sandbox example? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I found the solution. I had to make parent height:'inherit' from it's parent  and then children height as 100%